# Embed questions or answers on my website

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice to be able to embed an iframe on my website and have an answer or a question simply displayed in SO's colors.

For example, I'd just have to write:

```
<iframe src="http://embed.stackoverflow.com/a/23776447/851498"></iframe>
```

And the answer would be shown in the middle of my blog article, or whatever.